# Retrieve last variable from a function in php

Tags: php, function

I have a function which looks like this:

```
function eco($a, $c, $d, $e, $g) {
    $f= (($a/$c)/ $d)*$e;
    $h=$f/$g;
}
```

when I call this function and echo the results, nothing is displayed

```
$ok = eco(9,9,9,89,89);
echo $ok;
```

Actually, I need the value of `$h` for further calculations but am not able to retrieve it. How do I display the value of `$h`?

Comment: so what do you expect ? You have not returned any value .

Comment: even if I echo it within the function, it is not stored within the new variable $ok

Comment: `return $h` add last line

Comment: Soon on StackOverflow: "how do I type with keyboard?" Seriously, if you do not know even such a basic thing like `return`, you should pay for courses or something.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you rarely accept answers to your questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no other answer mentions what [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) actually does, I'll have to jot it down here:

> *return* returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.
>
> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.

So, you should do `return $h`. When you put it at the end of your function, you do not have to worry about `return` "immediately ending execution of the current function", since your function is already at the end of it's execution.

```
function eco($a, $c, $d, $e, $g) {
    $f= (($a/$c)/ $d)*$e;
    $h=$f/$g;

    return $h;
}
```

Next time read the docs thoroughly. Also read [Returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).

Answer (score 5):

you have to return value from function `eco`

```
 function eco($a, $c, $d, $e, $g) {
     $f= (($a/$c)/ $d)*$e;
     $h= $f/$g;
     return $h;
 }
```

Comment: You sure giving OP `return $f/$g;` is a good idea? `return $h;` is more readable. And taking into account OP didn't know about `return` a second ago, returning the result of expression might confuse him.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `return` for get any value from function,
something like this

```
function foo($value)
{
   return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `$h` from function

```
function eco($a, $c, $d, $e, $g) {
    $f= (($a/$c)/ $d)*$e;
    $h=$f/$g;
    return $h;
}

$ok = eco(9,9,9,89,89);
echo $ok;
```